# Обход всех вершин графа

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Необходимо найти из заданной вершины графа кратчайший путь по всем вершинам данного графа(без возвращения в начальную точку, т.е. цепь/путь).
Предполагается что граф будет полный ориентированный.

Этакая задача поиска гамильтонового пути, только с учетом что в каждую вершину можно возвращаться сколько угодно раз.

Может есть какие-то модификации или уже готовые решения?

Мне подойдет как полностью раскрытый ответ, так и ссылка на источник с материалом по вышеописанной теме или даже небольшой намек: "в какую сторону копать".

Comment: Как вариант, используйте алгоритм Форда в любой его реализации(стек, очередь, приоритетная очередь).

Comment: Несовсем понимаю как он подойдет? Он же для поиска кратчайшего пути от выделенной вершины  до всех вершин графа. А необходимо найти путь проходящий через все вершины но с возможностью возвращения в вершины(этакая модификация задачи коммивояжёра)

Comment: путь и цепь - 2 разные вещи..

Comment: Алгоритм Форда строит кратчайший ПУТЬ взвешенного ориентированного графа.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за уточнения в терминологии, интересует тогда ЦЕПЬ.

Comment: Не за что. Обращайтесь.

Comment: А в части моего изначального вопроса?) Какой алгоритм может помочь?  В части нахождения маршрута, ибо судя по описанию ЦЕПЬ, это частный случай маршрута, как и ПУТЬ.

Comment: Почитайте про SSSP - алгоритмы. Во всяком случаи SSSP все равно являются частными случаями алгоритма Лестера Форда. Можете посмотреть алгоритмы Борувки, Ярника (Прима) и Крускала. Ну и помочь может усиленное понимание того, что вы будете делать) Если что спрашивайте еще.

Comment: Почитаю. Попробую перефразировать мой изначальный вопрос. Есть ориентированный граф(для простоты предположим что полный). Случайным образом выбирается стартовая точка(вершина). Необходимо найти кратчайший маршрут проходящий по ВСЕМ вершинам данного графа причем через вершину можно проходить несколько раз. Возвращаться в конце в начальную точку ненужно. Допусти есть граф(в примере используется неориентированный) АБСД веса АС=6, АБ=3, БД=15, БС=1, ДС=40, АД=10. Стартовая точка А, тогда кратчайший маршрут А->Б->C->Б->Д и равен 3+1+1+15=20

Comment: Что вам не понятного? Вы почитайте сначала, что бы хотя бы область определения понимать. Я ваш вопрос изначально понял. Вас тут ни кто не тролит. Еще раз повторяю: ПОЧИТАЙТЕ ПРО АЛГОРИТМЫ SSSP, БОРУВКИ, ЯРНИКА И КРУСКАЛА, как только научитесь гуглить сразу поймете что это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос. Еще раз хотите перефразироватьxD

Comment: Я почитаю, и также не пытался Вас тролить. Я просто решил уточнить на тот случай если изначально некорректно выразился.

Comment: Если ответ не понятен, вносите уточнения прямо в ответ.